# Creating an Enum value from Model First design using EF 6.1

Tags: c#, powershell, enums, entity-framework-6

I simply want to find out **how to create a column in an entity as an Enum type using Model First design.**

In the attached image, you can see that I created a simple Console application (on the right pane) and added an EDM model with one entity named Teacher (on the left).

I clicked on the EDM designer and selected "Add new Enum Type" (which you see in the middle pane). The 3 types are Permanent, Contract, and Guest with respective values inside the TeacherType Enum Type of 1,2,3.

**How can I convert the TeacherType **property** on the left pane to actually be the **Enum** value TeacherType in the middle pane?**
[image]

Also, if you update your model which in turn will update the DB, will you lose your changes? With Model First, I believe not, but with DataBase First, I believe you will. Is there also a way to do the same thing I'm doing with DataBase First?

Code First is good, but I feel it still has a ways to go because of all the Powershell commands you need to manually do and all the "extra baggage" like defining relationships, FK's, seeding, etc all in the code. This takes up **a lot of time** and I feel can easily be done in a designer faster and with less mistakes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either right click on the property and select "Convert To Enum" which will create a new enum or right-click on the property and select "Properties" and then in the Properties window select your enum type in the "Type" row. Note that the "Convert to Enum" menu option will only show up if the property is already of a type that can be an underlying type for enum (i.e. byte, short, int or long - note EDM type system does not support unsigned types). If your property happens to be of a different type (a default type of a newly created property is string) you won't see the "Convert to Enum" menu option (because string is not a valid underlying type for an enum type) . To see this option in the menu you would have to go first to the properties and change the type to one of the underlying enum types.

With regards to the Code First usage - EF Designer now supports creating a Code First model from the database so you no longer have to configure your relationships manually for existing databases.

Comment: Pawel, I'm sampling a Code First model from the database now --- pretty cool. I added two tables from the DB into the application. It created a Model file with the DbSet entities along with the properties and associations. It also created separate POCO classes for each table. Question is: what if I need to add/update/delete a property? I know I can change the POCO classes to add/update/delete properties and reflect that same change in the Model class. How can I reflect that change I make in the code back into the database?

Comment: You need to decide if you want to do code first or database first (with code first model). If you have an existing test database and you don't care about the data you can create a Code First model from the existing database and then get rid of the Db and continue to evolve your database through the code (ideally using migrations). If you can't do that you should evolve the database and recreate your model each time you need it.

Comment: So, I would #1, drop the DB in sql server; #2, how do you migrate the changes you made in the code to the new physical sql DB; or #3) if I just want to skip the migrations, I can re-create my model through what I said in my last post, but HOW TO I PERSIST MY MODEL NOW TO THE PHYSICAL DB?

Comment: After dropping the database just run the app and EF will see there is no database and will create one for you. If you use migrations (which I strongly recommend) you each time you add a migration you run the `Update-Database` command and it will update the database accordingly

Comment: OK great --- almost there... I agree migrations is the best choice. That way, you won't lose your data. However, I can't find the "Update Database" command anywhere from any file in the project or on the menu.....

Comment: You run it from the Package Manager Console - I would suggest reading  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx

Comment: I see... I took a look. The only commands I would need to run would be the "Enable-Migrations", "Add-Migration" (when I add/update/delete properties), & "Update-Database" (to persist the tables - with the new properties - to the database). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be missing some of the steps please take a look at the following specifically chnging the value type in properties

http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework5/enum-in-entity-framework5.aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/efdesign/archive/2011/08/12/enums-in-the-entity-designer.aspx